# How to compare dates in a sql script to progress database?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

We have a field in our progress database which is DATETIME-TZ so an example of the data is "23/05/2019 12:11:16.099" -  I'm need some help to compare dates in this field with an SQL select statement

In progress procedure editor, I can compare dates easily, for example

select date(bond-no) from accadd where date(bond-no) <= Today

This works perfectly, but i need to get this info via sql for a web page and just get an error, even breaking the field down as a substring and making the date back up doesn't seem to work

SELECT date(""bond-no"") FROM accadd WHERE date(""bond-no"") <= Date()

Have tried variations on the above and this too...

DATE(SUBSTRING(""bond-no"",4,2),SUBSTRING(""bond-no"",1,2),SUBSTRING(""bond-no"",7,4))

This should return just dates earlier than today, but just get the old syntax incorrect message, so i'm missing something somewhere

[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Syntax error in SQL statement at or about ") FROM accadd WHERE" (10713)

Answer (score 1):

Using the SQL Editor in PDSOE which uses JDBC on a datetime (no -tz) field:

```
SELECT "bond-no" FROM pub.accadd WHERE "bond-no" <= CURDATE()
```

To use a static date:

```
SELECT "bond-no" FROM pub.accadd WHERE "bond-no" <= TO_DATE('5/31/2019')
```

Or:

```
SELECT "bond-no" FROM pub.accadd WHERE "bond-no" <= { d'5/31/2019' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to quote the field name because it contains a dash but your sample code has doubled quotes.  Have you tried:

```
SELECT date("bond-no") FROM accadd WHERE date("bond-no") <= Date()
```

I'm not sure why you are doing it but I don't think that you need the DATE() function around the "bond-no".  DATE() is a 4gl function so it works when you are at the "procedure editor" and using the embedded SQL but the OpenEdge SQL92 engine does not have a DATE() function.  There is, however, a TO_DATE() function:
  https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf%2Fto-date.html%23wwID0EXIOS

The following works with the sports2000 database and using sqlexp (rather than embedded sql at the procedure editor):

```
select * from pub.order where orderdate < '1/1/1999'
```

I also added a datetime-tz field called "tstamp", initialized it and tried it like so:

```
select tstamp from pub.order where tstamp < '1/1/1999'
```

which worked fine too.

Comment: Yes, the sql statement is loaded into a string before being executed so I have to double quote all of the fields with dashes, like "SELECT date(""bond-no"") FROM accadd WHERE date(""bond-no"") <= Date()"

Comment: The table name should also be prefixed with the PUB schema.  I.e. "pub.accadd".

Comment: `code` CAST(SUBSTRING(""bond-no"",7,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(""bond-no"",4,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(""bond-no"",1,2) AS Date)

Comment: Why do you want to cast the date as a date?  That seems pointless.